# Making a mounted volume searchable

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search

OK, this is something that should be ridiculously easy to do in Windows 7, but it simply doesn't work.  All I want to do is find all files with a certain extension within a folder and its subfolders.  Placing a `*.sln` in the search box in Explorer yields no results.  `.sln` doesn't work either.  The `kind:` and `type:` filters don't seem very useful either.

Without resorting to opening the command prompt or Powershell, is there a way in Explorer to list all files that have a particular file extension?

**Update**

I've found out the most probable cause of search not working, and updated the question accordingly.  The directory I'm trying to search in is included inside of a "Mounted Volume"; in other words, a second hard drive is mounted to C:\Users\UserName\Folder, and searching inside of that folder does not work.

Is there a way to get Windows 7 to search within a mounted volume?  The folder does not even appear in the indexed locations tree.

Comment: It should work as you tried (`*.sln`) - just tested it to be sure...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have disabled some of the Windows search components? *.sln as well as .sln and ext:sln are working without problems here.

Comment: I haven't personally disabled any search components; this computer is set up through an IT department.  Do you have any advice on where I could check for the status of the components needed by search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now; although I could not add indexing to the mounted folder, I was able to add a secondary mount for the volume.  In my case, I mapped the S drive to the volume, while still maintaining my home directory mount.  Once that was added, I was able to add indexing to the S drive.